# Finding the anti-derivative of complex absolute value

Tags: complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals, absolute-value

I am wondering if there is an anti-derivative of the complex absolute value and if it exists, how to find it.

I am looking for

$
\int |z|^2 dz = ?
$

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. One the complex plane, only analytic functions have derivatives or anti-derivatives. And neither $|z|$ nor $|z|^2$ is analytic anywhere. These functions are real-valued everywhere, and the only complex-analytic functions whose images are not 2-dimensional are constants.

Integration in $\Bbb C$ is along curves. So to have an integral, you must define the curve it is along. The only exception is when the funtion you are analyzing is conservative, so the integral along any closed curve is always $0$. In that case, it doesn't matter which path you take between two points - the value of the integral is dependent on only the end points. However in $\Bbb C$, the condition for being conservative happens to coincide with the condition for being analytic. Thus you cannot use integration to define an anti-derivative unless the integrand is analytic.